# Why specifically Azure storage account & Azure key vault service makes proactive handshake request while launching the application?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-keyvault

In my .net core web api application Im using many Azure service but specifically "Azure storage account" & "Azure key vault" services make proactive handshake request while launching the application itself which I found I'm lost & need understand why these Azure service making proactive handshake request while launching the application itself, is there any way to avoid this proactive handshake request happening during application launch?

Attached the screenshot to highlight above mentioned proactive handshake request

[sample fiddler traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AGjC.png)

Comment: Could it be possible that you have stored your storage account credentials (like connection string) in Azure Key Vault?

Comment: No. On development environment, the connection strings are hard coded on config files

Answer (score 0):

If you enable [HTTPS decryption](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/decrypthttps) in Fiddler, then you can see what is actually sent. At startup for Azure Key Vault, it will typically download a list of all the secrets and then for each one download the secret. Like what this picture below shows:

[image]